# identify memory leak of closure with memwatch-node

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, closures

My Node.js project suffering memory leaking, I've already set variables to null in closure, I mean, I know code like this:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var c = 0;
example_func(c, func(){
    console.log(b);
});
```

Will cause memory leaks, so I add some code to set these variables to null;

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var c = 0;
example_func(c, func(){
    console.log(b);
    a = null;
    b = null;
    c = null;
});
```

But I still got leaks, so I try to use `memwatch-node` to figure out what's wrong with my code.

And the result shows that `closure` causing the leak, but not specified enough to target.

I've got the JSON like this

```
 { what: 'Closure',
   '+': 12521,
   size: '520.52 kb',
   '-': 5118,
   size_bytes: 533016 },
```

And I am wondering if I could get more specific details about which closure is leaking.

I've assigned name for all closures, but still not work.

Comment: That's an object literal. In itself, it has nothing to do with "closure", apart from having one of its properties set to the string 'Closure', which might as well be '1982 Datsun Cherry'.

Comment: So which kind of object would do that? I do not set "closure" by myself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm embarrassed, I can better see what your question is about now. I've been into the memwatch documentation but cannot find evidence of a `what: 'Closure'` section in a diff report. [This](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/) indicates that closure leaks are reported but not in that manner. It's somewhat confusing.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. I've add some details.

Comment: The source code in `node-memwatch` related to `closure` is `        case HeapGraphNode::kClosure:
            type.append("Closure");
            break;` in src/heapdiff.cc Line 171, and `kClosure` is defined by V8 engine, I guess.

Comment: Yes I can see that a specific Closure report would be very useful but it appears that memwatch, at its current state of development, only reports closure leaks in bulk. I think you may be stuck with spotting potential leaks manually. Once spotted, you can try using javascript's slightly awkward `delete` operator rather than nulling out with `null` - this will purge entries in the symbol table. BTW, the question is much better now.

Comment: Another approach: Once you have decided which functions to target, it's sometimes possible to organise the code such that closures contain only the bare minimum of variables to make them work. The reorganisation takes some skill and is in the category of "more art than science". If you are working with constructors/classes, this exercise can test your understanding of inheritance.

Comment: actually, in my code I use both `delete` and `null`, but `delete` could only delete property of an object, not an variable created by `var`. I know using `null` will clear the symbol table, and that could make sure that GC will release it, that's exactly what I want, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get more specific about which closure. memwatch gets a dump of the v8 heap and then takes differences of it and reports leaks if, after 5 successive garbage collection events, that object type count continued to grow.

Also, I believe you are confused on what closures are. [The MDN page on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) gives a good description. A closure is not a variable, but a scope that enables functions to retain references and continue to work when used in a part of the code where those variable references would not otherwise be available.

If you pass functions around keep a reference to that function, it's closure could reference other closures. So, it's possible you have a single closure that could have a lot in it.

Do this: disable parts of your code until memwatch stops complaining. Then, look at that code. If you are still confused, post more details in this question.